# Visual Studio Code Error: "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc build active file' terminated with exit code -1."

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run C on my remote SSH and still keep getting an error with running my C code for my project. I've tried most of the recommended solutions, but none seem to work. I have also confirmed that gdb and gcc were downloaded onto my computer and work.
Here is all my .vscode files

c_cpp_properties.json :

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Pipe Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "pipeTransport": {
        "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "pipeProgram": "/usr/bin/ssh",
        "pipeArgs": [],
        "pipeCwd": ""
      },
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Pipe Attach",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
      "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
      "pipeTransport": {
        "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "pipeProgram": "/usr/bin/ssh",
        "pipeArgs": [],
        "pipeCwd": ""
      },
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Attach",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": false,
      "cwd": "/home/ecelrc/students/hgf286/312stuff/prog1_hgf286",
      "program": "/home/ecelrc/students/hgf286/312stuff/prog1_hgf286/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcBatchPath": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "gdb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useMsvc": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warnings": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Wshadow",
    "-Wformat=2",
    "-Wcast-align",
    "-Wconversion",
    "-Wsign-conversion",
    "-Wnull-dereference"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcWarnings": [
    "/W4",
    "/permissive-",
    "/w14242",
    "/w14287",
    "/w14296",
    "/w14311",
    "/w14826",
    "/w44062",
    "/w44242",
    "/w14905",
    "/w14906",
    "/w14263",
    "/w44265",
    "/w14928"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.enableWarnings": true,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warningsAsError": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.linkerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includeSearch": [
    "*",
    "**/*"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.excludeSearch": [
    "**/build",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.*",
    "**/.*/**",
    "**/.vscode",
    "**/.vscode/**"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useAddressSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useUndefinedSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLeakSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.showCompilationTime": false
}
```

task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                ""
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486598/the-prelaunchtask-c-c-gcc-9-build-active-file-terminated-with-exit-code-1#:%7E:text=Maybe%20this%20is%20a%20problem%20with%20the%20path,tasks.json%20in%20the.vscode%20folder%2C%20in%20the%20arguments%20part.)
and also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519454/error-the-prelaunchtask-c-c-g-exe-build-active-file-terminated-with-exi)

Comment: How are you compiling the file? By using code runner, some debugger, or typing gcc?

Comment: @IbrahimHasaan their question very clearly has a build task...

Comment: @starball I didn’t know what a build task was